# Is it possible to insert AppScript triggers to a Google Sheet from PHP

Tags: php, firebase, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Is it possible to insert triggers to a Google Sheet that is owned by the same domain from PHP.

A bit of background: The writers of my wordpress site love using Google Sheet, and i would like to keep the sheet data in-sync with Firebase. I have figured out how to use AppScript to trigger auto syncing to Firebase through this [tutorial](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/sheets-to-firebase-33132e31935b).

Now I would like to be able to, when receive a sheet url from writer/admin, in PHP, make it `sync with firebase` by inserting AppScript trigger to the sheet.

I just want to know if it's possible, and where to start...

Comment: Using the Apps Script API you will not be able to create triggers. (As mentioned by @TheAddonDepot ). Perhaps creating a single script that with a time driven trigger updates the Firebase DB with each sheet's changes. Let us know what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Apps Script has built-in PHP triggers, but maybe you can deploy/build your Apps Script as an API and then call that API from your PHP code?

You can either execute functions individually ( https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute ) or call the Apps Script as a GET/POST with the doGet() and doPost() functions.

Comment: Its not possible to create triggers with the Apps Script API. See [limitations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute#limitations).

Comment: True, since API can't create triggers, i can't call from PHP to add trigger to the sheet. I wonder if API can add a addon/custom-menu to the sheet, like a toggle switch `Sync with firebase`, when the toggle is on, it will start the sync trigger. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

### Use Apps Script API - Method: scripts.run

If you have a backend language that you can handle on your own, you can run a function when you receive a new sheet URL by using the [Method: scripts.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/scripts/run) instead of creating a trigger.

### Reference

- [Apps Script API - PHP](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/script/v1/php/latest/)